# Adding scenario outputs/ returning data from step and having it displayed

Tags: php, behat

I know that in the Java implementation of Cucumber, there is a way to add 'extra' data to the resulting output, i.e, a bit of information from the run, etc. In the reports, this data would appear under the step that added that data.

I was wondering if there was equivalent functionality in the Behat php version of Cucumber, and if so, how to go about doing it. I have been unable to find anything online that would easily point me to this.

Answer (score 0):

It should work using the PHP's default methods like `echo`, `var_dump`, `print_r`.

Create a log method in your base object with `echo` , and add `implode` for arrays
+ use `-vvv` for increased verbosity.
For specific type of details it may depend on the reporting you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. It could also be that I am using PhpStorm which uses its own formatter that might not support this